# A function to return a class which extends a derived class of an abstract class

Tags: node.js, typescript, abstract-class

I would like to make a funciton to return a class which extends a derived class of an abstract class in Typescript. I think [Abstract Construct Signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-construct-signatures) should be the one I should use. However, Typescript prompts "Non-abstract class 'SayHelloDerived' does not implement all abstract members of 'Base'." Here is a simplified code.

```
// @errors: 18052
abstract class Base {
  abstract getName(): string;
  printName() {
    console.log("a")
  }
}
class Derived extends Base {
  getName() {
    return "";
  }
}
function makeSayHelloDerived(DerivedBase: new () => Base) {
  return class SayHelloDerived extends DerivedBase {
    sayHello() {
      console.log("hello!");
    }
  }
}

const Derived2 = makeSayHelloDerived(Derived);
const derived2 = new Derived2;
derived2.sayHello();

const Derived3 = makeSayHelloDerived(Base);
const derived3 = new Derived3;
derived3.sayHello();
```

[Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAEFMCdoe2gZwFygIwA4AMBWATAFACGARogC7REDG5o1ANkYoqAELOSgDeBoopClVqgA5pHIA5IgFtIACgCUqIQEsAdqIDcfUAAdoGqbIWKeu-tTjrEcBpAB0DOKPkAiIm8W6AvgT+MzKwAIjCqAG6QACagkAAe5JDqUawciFy8-OLGckrm-PzQEgCu0Oqgbm46-H5+AGbF6rSq1qAyRADWkADKRACeABKQDM6hhpFR8mMR0WmQqOqQAO6geQC8AHzsnGaZoEXkpeWBLKC9g8OjYROxCUkpoNMTc-kFiP1DI3B5ewX01rZ7E4XO4ABaXOAAQi81QKfhq-gIBCsNjoT2ieFAazanR6Hwh6MmhMUOhRFFAUWuGKxoEWK0JeB0lPGGIc7wuXyUOmRALRVKiAGYae0uudPlcWZM5iSeaiKfyhdi6Y8FUyFWz8ZyZUA)

The second error is expected, but the first one is not.

I expect Typescript can recognize parameter "DerivedBase" in function "makeSayHelloDerived" as a derived class of abstract "Base" class. It should not prompt any error, but it prompts now. I have googled around and search stackOverflow here about "Abstract Construct Signature," but no luck. Did I have anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution would be to change the type of the parameter to `new () => Derived`, but I suppose that's not what you want - you want to accept *any* non-abstract class that inherits from `Base`.

I'm not certain how exactly this works, but I managed to do this by explicitly adding the concrete method signature to the type of the construct signature:

```
function makeSayHelloDerived(DerivedBase: new () => Base & { getName(): string }) {
  return class SayHelloDerived extends DerivedBase {
    sayHello() {
      console.log("hello!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! How come you can think of this solution. Unluckily I have got many abstract members in the real application, but I think I can make another interface to hold them to replace { getName(): string} position. Quite trouble but at least work.

Comment: It was just a lucky guess :-) Maybe you can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to get rid of the "abstractness" as well

Comment: Would you tell me how I can use mapped type to get rid of the "abstractness"?

Comment: I mean like `{[P in keyof Base]: Base[P];}`, that way you don't have to spell out the many members of the interface

Comment: Ah, I got it. I thought I should only include the abstract members of the Base. However, I found including all members also works. Thanks a lot!